# Issue in using Fakes assembly to test office 365 sharepoint provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, provider-hosted-app

I have a office 365 sharepoint provider hosted app. I need to use "Fakes" assembly for unit testing. I am using VS2013 as IDE. I am not able to get it work.

I followed below mentioned steps:

1. I created New Sharepoint Test project.
2. I imported SharePoint.Client.dll and SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll.
3. I added corresponding fakes assembly by right clicking on assemblies.

I tried to mock clientcontext and web objects, but I am not able use them.

I am posting my sample code to be tested:

```
private static TermCollection FetchDataFromTermStore(SharePointContextToken contextToken, string hostUrl)
    {
        var terms;
        //Get client context
        Uri projectSiteUri = new Uri(hostUrl);
        var token = TokenHelper.GetAccessToken(contextToken, projectSiteUri.Authority).AccessToken;
        using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(projectSiteUri.ToString(), token))
        {
            //Get Taxonomy Session
            TaxonomySession taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);
            taxonomySession.UpdateCache();
            TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
            TermGroup termGroup = termStore.Groups.GetByName(Constants.TERM_SET_GROUP_NAME);
            TermSet ptsTermSet = termGroup.TermSets.GetByName(Constants.TERM_SET_NAME);
            terms = ptsTermSet.Terms;
            clientContext.Load(terms);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Trace.TraceInformation("Got taxonomy terms");
       }
       return terms;
    }
```

I am not able to imagine test method to test above mentioned method. Should I use SharePoint emulators with Fakes assembly? Please suggest me a way to write test method for this function.

Thanks in advance.